# After closing FilterWriter why it is working?

Tags: java, exception, io

In the code below, I closed the `FilterWriter` using `close()` method before writing anything to the `FilterWriter` and once the stream has been closed, if we try to invoke the methods `write()` or `flush()` on the `FilterWriter` it should cause an `IOException` to be thrown.

But here calling the `write()` method is working fine and no exception is thrown. Why?

```
import java.io.FilterWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter(10);
            FilterWriter filterWriter = new FilterWriter(writer) {};
            filterWriter.close();
            filterWriter.write(65);
            String str = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
```

Comment: Have you checked what `close()` actually does? How it's implementation looks like?

Comment: @Tom yes I checked it and got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because closing a `FilterWriter` invokes the `close` method of the underlying `Writer`, which is the one you passed in the constructor.

Your underlying `Writer` is a `StringWriter` whose [`close` implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/05a764f4ffb8030d6b768f2d362c388e5aabd92d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/StringWriter.java) does nothing at all. (which is also what the [documentation for the `close` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringWriter.html#close()) says).

So when you try to write to it after invoking `close`, no exception is actually thrown.

Answer (score 0):

close() function of FilterWriter calls the close() function of the underlying writer.
In your case the underlying writer is of type StringWriter and according to javadoc for the close() function of Stringwriter [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)

> Closing a StringWriter has no effect.

Hence you do not encounter any error.